# Getting MFCC from a spectrogram time/ frequency series array

Tags: python, signal-processing, mfcc

I have several spectrogra time/frequency [500,1024] files.

I need to calculate the MFCC of these files. There are lot's of the library for calculating MFCC on a raw audio file but I'm looking a method in python for calculating directly from np.array.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with librosa, as it allows to pass in spectrograms instead of audio waveform using the parameter `S`.

I am assuming that you have a STFT magnitude spectrogram (linear spectrogram with phase discarded). Then need to convert this into a mel-filtered spectrogram, perform log-scaling, and then do the DCT-2 and truncation to obtain MFCC coefficients. Skeleton code below:

```py
import librosa
import numpy

# TODO: you need to provide these
sr = my_samplerate
my_stft

mels = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(S=my_stft, sr=sr, n_mels=64)
log_mels = librosa.core.amplitude_to_db(mels, ref=numpy.max)
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(S=log_mels, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20)
```

See the [librosa API reference](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/feature.html) for more details.